# Failed to install GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2

I get this in the terminal:

> GRUB failed to install to the following devices:
>   /dev/dm-0 /dev/dm-1  Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your
>   computer may not start up properly. Writing GRUB to boot device failed
>   - continue?

And then I can choose "yes" or "no". I have absolutely no idea what any of that means, except the "your computer may not start up properly"-part, which sounds horrifying! 
If I click "No", it goes back in the circle I came from. And if I click "Yes"... all hell breaks loose?

To be sure, I don't understand half of what's written in here. I am not literate in Computer. Is there a patient soul out there who can explain to me step by step what to do?

My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad-x250.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 1 LTS
64-bit.

Comment: What install option did you select? Are you dual booting with Windows, or did you select erase entire drive and install using LVM and encrypted entire drive. I do not know LVM, but dm devices are related to LVM which uses advanced volumes (not partitions). Unless you  have to have encryption, LVM is recommended only for knowledgeable users.

Comment: I don't know which action got the ball rolling. Here's the history: First, I had Zoom installed. Then I had trouble during a Zoom session, looked for updates and there weren't any, so I removed it to install it again. But now it was gone from the Ubuntu Software Centre. So I searched how to install Zoom via Terminal. One instruction is to run the installation file with Software Install. I tried to install Software Install, but it tells me that sessioninstaller must first be removed. When trying to remove this, the process seemed to freeze and got no further for a long time.

Comment: Then I opened the terminal and typed "sudo apt-get update" but it didn't work and told me something was being used by something else

Comment: it gave me a command line to fix it, something with "dkpg" or I don't remember it, I'm sorry. In running this, it came up with a grey window saying I need to install GRUB and it is recommended to do so on all devices. I chose all devices, that's when I got this output.

Comment: Yes, I have recently installed Windows and now have dual booting.

Comment: You cannot have two update processes running at same time. I often open synaptic ot see exact file name & then use terminal to add package. But when I forget to close synaptic it gives that error. Issues with dpkg normally need to be resolved first, but that is after install. You cannot update live installer, but should be able to add some software for testing. Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not post full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair